# How to display Fragment containing custom SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, surfaceview

This following setup does not work, does anybody know why (I cant seem to find examples of custom surface view in a fragment).

My surfaceView class is just hollow at the moment:

```
class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

My XML for the fragment looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:background="#000000" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <com.example.android.fragments.MySurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

And then in the actual Fragment itself on the OnCreateView I call :

```
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

Any ideas why this does not hang together ?

It something to do with the XML because when I do

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to show your custom SurfaceView ('MySurfaceView') in the fragment, then just do the following:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new MySurfaceView(getActivity());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple if you check :

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

you will see that on onCreateView you should return View which will be used to present  Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView( String name , Context context , AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateView( name , context , attrs );
    }
```

you should return View so basically you should just return there your

```
MySurfaceView
```

//edit

```
public MySurfaceView ( Context context , AttributeSet attrs , int defStyle )
    {
        super( context , attrs , defStyle );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MySurfaceView ( Context context , AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        super( context , attrs );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MySurfaceView ( Context context )
    {
        super( context );
    }
```

try to implement all 3 constructors of this view

Comment: I think your answer is not correct because "To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout."  The SurfaceView is not the root view, its just a component in the XML document as I also have a button there aswel. So this is what I am doing with "return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);" I am inflating and returning the root view that contains the SurfaceView.